# XML creation at runtime using XSLT

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have the following requirement : I have one XML like :

```
<RunSettings>
<IsWfm>true</IsWfm>
<LogAndTrace>"c:\logs"</LogAndTrace>
<DateFormat>DD.MM.YYYY</DateFormat>
:
:
</RunSettings>
```

Now I want to use XSLT to make different XMLs using this XML. I mean I need different values in the tags everytime Like once the value of ISwfm is true then next time it will be false . The same with all the nodes.

Please suggest how to do that. I am new to this and have checked XPath etc. but didn't find a perfect solution.

Comment: You mean you have sets of values for the different tags, and you want to generate XML documents with all combinations of tags with these values? Could you post different output examples?

Comment: Yes please post samples of desired output. BTW XPath will not be able to create new XML elements at runtime; it can only select existing nodes. But you can do it in XSLT 1.0. For conditionals, see `<xsl:choose>`.

Comment: yes paul you are correct , The xml that i posted will be the input and at runtime i need to create different xmls based on combination of tags value Like : one xml where the value of tag <Iswfm> is true , in another the value of Iswfm tag is false , then in another the valus of tag <logAndTrace> is different. e.g One xml :   <RunSettings>
<IsWfm>false</IsWfm>
<LogAndTrace>"c:\logs"</LogAndTrace>
<DateFormat>DD.MM.YYYY</DateFormat>
</RunSettings>   another xml where rest of the tags have same value but second tag will change value.

Comment: Can you edit your question and put the examples in there, where they can be formatted nicely?

Comment: The xml that i posted will be the input and at runtime i need to create different xmls based on combination of tags value Like : one xml where the value of tag <Iswfm> is true , in another the value of Iswfm tag is false , then in another the valus of tag <logAndTrace> is different.                                                                      e.g : One xml : <RunSettings> <IsWfm>false</IsWfm> <LogAndTrace>"c:\logs"</LogAndTrace> <DateFormat>DD.MM.YYYY</DateFormat> </RunSettings> another xml where rest of the tags have same value but second tag will change value